# Ruby: `gsub': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, gsub

```
def export_no_sdesc(item_no = " ", make = " ", model = " ", list_price = " ", long_desc = " ", global_image_path = " ")
final_image_path = global_image_path + item_no + ".jpg"
final_thumbs_path = global_image_path + "thumbs/" + item_no + ".jpg"
Dir.glob("body.tmp") do |filename|
    body = file_as_string(filename)
    body = body.gsub("item_no", item_no).gsub("image_path", final_image_path).gsub("image_thumb", final_thumbs_path)
    body = body.gsub("part_make", make).gsub("part_model", model).gsub("long_desc", long_desc).gsub("list_price", list_price)
    File.open('page_export.html', 'a') do |x|
        x.puts body
        x.close
    end
  end
end
```

The above function is giving me fits. First, it reads in some strings from a text file. Then, it reads in a text file that's a template for part of a HTML table. Next, it replaces certain keywords in the template file with the contents of the strings, and lastly, it pushes it all to a new text file (page_export.html).

The problem here is that some fields that are being imported in the text file are blank, or at least, I think that's the problem. Either way, I get this error:

```
john@starfire:~/code/ruby/idealm_db_parser$ ruby html_export.rb
html_export.rb:34:in `gsub': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
from html_export.rb:34:in `export_no_sdesc'
from html_export.rb:31:in `glob'
from html_export.rb:31:in `export_no_sdesc'
from html_export.rb:82
from html_export.rb:63:in `each'
from html_export.rb:63
from html_export.rb:56:in `glob'
from html_export.rb:56
```

To remedy this, not only did I declare a whitespace as a default argument for each string, but in another part of the script, I loop through each string - and if it's empty, I append a whitespace. Still no luck.

I have a function that's almost identical to the one above, but it operates over a slightly different set of data - one that doesn't have any empty strings - and it works great. I've also tested the code that appends the whitespace, and it works fine, too.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: thanks meagar for display fix :)

Comment: Yeah sorry, still trying to wrap my head around Markdown...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply, one of your function arguments is `nil`. It doesn't matter if you'ved supplied default empty strings if you're passing a `nil` in.

We can't possibly tell which argument is nil from the code provided, so check them all, and, assuming an error is thrown, start checking them individually. Add the following to the top of your function:

```
[item_no, make, model, list_price, long_desc, global_image_path].each do|i|
  throw "nil argument" if i.nil?
end
```

---

**Update**

Default arguments don't prevent you from passing in `nil`. They only come into effect if you don't supply *anything*.

Here:

```
def test(x = 3)
  puts x
end

test()    # writes '3'
test(nil) # writes 'nil'
```

Comment: I guess I'm not quite understanding the concept of 'nil'... is nil its own datatype? As in, if something's nil, I can't append a whitespace to it, because a whitespace is of type string?

Comment: `nil` is of type `NilClass`, and you cannot append strings to it. Whatever checking you think you're doing external to this function obviously isn't working. The only way that your error could be caused is if one of your arguments to `gsub` is nil.

Comment: they won't be nil, since in the method they get default values, isn't it?

Comment: @m4risU That's not how default values work. They can be nil, and almost certainly are nil. See my update.

Comment: Oh wow. Didn't know that, thanks a lot. Is there any way to replace the nil value with an empty string, though? If there's no data, I just need the field to be blank.

Comment: @meagar You are right. I forgot that I can just ommit the argument with this definition.

Comment: @kivetros you can use `x.is_a? String` to see whether `x` is a string. You can also use `x = x || ""` to assign an empty string to `x` when `x` is  either nil or false.

Comment: @meagar still nothing, looks as if there might be a problem with body.tmp, too

Comment: @kivetros The error can *only* be caused by a `nil` argument to `gsub`. Since your first argument is a string literal in every case, the error **must** be one of the 2nd parameters is null.

Comment: This code here:
`content = ""
f = File.open("full_database_short.jma", "r")
 f.each_line do |line|
  if line.is_a? String
   puts line
  else 
   puts "nil"
  end
 end`

reveals to me that no line in the source file is nil. That means that there's a problem with body.tmp...

Comment: @kive `f.each_line` will obviously never return `nil`, that isn't a possible source of errors. What do you mean "there's a problem with body.tmp"? Is that not just a static file on the file system that you're opening?

Comment: Broke the `gsub` calls up into individual lines. The first one that breaks is trying to replace "long_desc" with this line:

`Automatic Box Taper, 78-8023-2448-9 Top Taping Head for 7A/7R, 78-8023-2449-7 Bottom Taping Head for 7A/7R, 7R Random Case Sealer Serial #2453`

EDIT: and @meagar, yes, you're right... didn't see your comment above my last one until after I posted, for some reason.

Comment: Gets worse. Even though I copied the above line and assigned it to a variable in irb (called 'code'), then called `code.class`, it returned String. But, even after the line `long_desc = long_desc || ""`, if I call `puts long_desc` in the script I'm working on, it returns `nil`. WTF?

Comment: [Problem is here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183574/ruby-why-is-there-a-nil-at-the-end-of-all-the-strings-in-my-array/5183697#5183697) Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    body = file_as_string(filename)
```

into

```
    throw body = file_as_string(filename)
```

If it gives you nil, then you have some problems with body.tmp file.

Comment: Well, this right here is the contents of 'body.tmp':

`<tr>
   <td>item_no</td>
   <td><a href="image_path" align="center"><img src="image_thumb"/></a></td>
  <td>Make: part_make<br />Model: part_model</br /><br />long_desc</td>
   <td>list_price</td>
 </tr>`

I'm almost certain that it's one of the parameters that I'm trying to pass, but I'll test this. Thanks.

Comment: Tried what you said, got this...

`john@starfire:~/code/ruby/idealm_db_parser$ ruby html_export.rb
html_export.rb:34:in `throw': uncaught throw `<tr> (NameError)
   <td>item_no</td>
   <td><a href="image_path" align="center"><img src="image_thumb" /></a></td>
   <td>Make: part_make<br />Model: part_model</br /><br />long_desc</td>
   <td>list_price</td>
  </tr>
'`

Investigating.